# parent this context is not defined in child scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I tried to acceess `current_series` in $.each loop,

However, it doesn't work, any idea?

## Exception

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: current_series is not defined(…)
```

## JS

```
$.each($scope.flights, function() {
    var current_series = this;
    $.each(current_series.data, function(){
      console.log(current_series)
    })
});
```

Comment: what is `$scope.flights`?

Comment: An array,  which is from angular

Comment: `$.each($scope.flights, function(current_series, key) {`

Comment: or : `angular.forEach($scope.flights, function(current_series, key) {`

Comment: `var current_series = this` What do you expect `this` to be ?

Comment: what do you want `current_series` to refer to

Comment: just log the stringified version of `this` object before current_series varialble. Because if `this = undefined` u will get the error as u stated in your question.

Comment: also use the Angular forEach : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach not jQuery\s

Comment: @ArunPJohny I comment other stuff, I need to access current_series to modify its value